# SQL - where condition for each column

Tags: sql, firebird, where-clause, firebird2.1

This is a general SQL question, but I if you must know the database is Firebird.

I have this table (simplified):

```
user  amount  type
--------------------
john  25      credit
john  20      debit
john  5       debit
john  15      credit
mike  15      credit
```

I want to have a result that looks like this, using a single query:

```
user  credit  debit
--------------------
john  40      25
mike  15      NULL
```

```
Where credit = SUM(amount) WHERE type=credit
   and debit = SUM(amount) WHERE type=debit
```

Basically I want to have multiple fields on the result based on a SUM of a field (in this case amount) but on different conditions (in this case type).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standard SQL would be:

```
SELECT "user",
    SUM(CASE WHEN type='credit' then amount END) as Credit,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type='debit' then amount END) as Debit
FROM
    "table"
GROUP BY
    "user"
```

Comment: +1, although you'll need to quote `"user"` (and match the case of the column declaration).  USER is a Firebird synonym for CURRENT_USER, which doesn't give quite the desired results in your query as currently written. :)

Comment: @pilcrow: You are right of course, but isn't this just a template? If you thought this query should be immediately runnable, you should have mentioned that `table` must be quoted too. :)

Comment: @Andriy - hey, crazy things can happen, people can use reserved words, I may as well fix it so that it could run as a real query. I assume `type` isn't reserved?

Comment: @Damien: Seems like it isn't, according to [this article](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-reskeywords-dropped.html). (*Update.* But it's considered to be a keyword nonetheless.)

Comment: @Andriy, true enough.  However, `user` is not everywhere a reserved word (MySQL and SQLite, at least) as `table` is, and it appeared to me to be the actual column name in use from the original post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how Firebird does it, but can you do something like:

```
SELECT user, 
sum(SELECT amount FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.user = t1.user AND type="credit" ) AS credit, 
sum(SELECT amount FROM table AS t3 WHERE t3.user = t1.user AND type="debit" ) AS debit
FROM table AS t1
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY user
```

I'm referencing what I think it would be in PostgreSQL, in case that helps you find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT credit.user_name, credit.cre, debit.deb
  FROM (SELECT user_name, SUM(amount) cre FROM t WHERE TYPE = 'credit' GROUP BY user_name) credit
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user_name, SUM(amount) deb
                     FROM t
                    WHERE TYPE = 'debit'
                    GROUP BY user_name) debit
    ON (credit.user_name = debit.user_name)
```